# How can a parameter be passed to a Saxon-B-processed XSL?

Tags: java, saxon

I am using Saxon-B 9.1.0.8 and XSL 2.0.

I have a XSL stylesheet, in which there is an `xsl:param` element:

```
<xsl:param name="lang"/>
```

And I am using the following code to do the transformation of my document:

```
try {
    Source xmlSource = new StreamSource(new File(xmlFilename));
    Source xsltSource = new StreamSource(new File(xslFilename));

    // create the transformer
    Processor processor = new Processor(false);
    XsltCompiler xsltCompiler = processor.newXsltCompiler();
    XsltExecutable xslt = xsltCompiler.compile(xsltSource);
    XsltTransformer xsltTransformer = xslt.load();
    xsltTransformer.setSource(xmlSource);

    // configure output
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    Serializer serializer = new Serializer();
    serializer.setOutputWriter(sw);
    serializer.setOutputProperty(Serializer.Property.INDENT, "yes");
    xsltTransformer.setDestination(serializer);

    // do it!
    xsltTransformer.transform();
} catch (SaxonApiException e) {
    logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
}
```

How should a value for this parameter be passed to the transformer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saxon uses the `QName` and `XdmAtomicValue` classes to pass in parameters:

```
QName langParam = new QName("lang");
xsltTransformer.setParameter(langParam, new XdmAtomicValue("default"));
```